# My Fn key broke - how to adjust keyboard lowlight on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

Normally Fn+F3 would turn off my keyboard lowlight but with my Fn key broken I can't find an alternative way? In my keyboard settings on Windows 7 turning off the backlight is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops provide a way to plug in a second keyboard and use it instead of the normal one.  Is this practical for your situation?